# How to force Kill process in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, process

Ok, I've tried in the task manager - it didn't worked. Then I've tried in command line by:

```
taskkill /im name.exe /F
```

And it says (it's a translation from polish, so it's not exact):

```
ERROR: can't end process "name.exe" with PID 6788.
Cause: Access denied.
```

Anybody encountered this? Any solution other then reboot?

Comment: You need to have administrative privileges, i.e. in Vista you will need an elevated token to do this.

Answer (score 3):

First, ensure you are running taskkill as an elevated administrator.

Then try Process Explorer from the Sysinternals Suite:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Finally, if a debugger is attached to the process, you may not be able to kill it and will need to log off the user session that the process is running under or even restart the machine.

Answer (score 3):

For a foolproof solution, just use [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) from Sysinternals (now owned by Microsoft)

Assuming you have the privileges `pskill` will kill any process. I've had processes that `TASKKILL` and various other methods wouldn't be able to terminate whereas `pskill` will. (This was for an installation routine, where I *needed* to kill the process to replace the executable)

Answer (score 2):

I tried all suggestions here and other places and just this one works for me in a similar case:
**Advanced Process Termination**:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/Advanced-Process-Termination.shtml
APT suggests 18 different ways to kill a process and has a user interface.
17th way worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

xKill is a similar app to Kill but it’s more advanced in the sense that it can run in the system tray and has a shortcut to activate kill mode. So if an application is not responding, just press Ctrl – Alt – BackSpace. This will activate the kill mode and clicking on any window will terminate that process. To deactivate the kill mode without killing any app, just press Esc.

Download:

[xKill](http://www.technize.com/?dl_id=157)

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32 api, after having set rights on pid.